# how to link a css to a html page?

Tags: html, css

I have an `index.html` and `style.css`. I currently use the inline css but I want to use a stylesheet. I have this code in my index.html just before my `</head>` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

and then i have this in my style.css

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

note both of those files are located in `public_html`. But whenever I open the index.html the background stays white and does not change to yellow.

how can i link the `style.css` to `index.html` ?

Comment: what is `/` for, in your `href`.. Remove that.

Just use `href="style.css"`

`/` is file or URI path separator, Here your `style.css` is in same directory/folder, hence no need to use `/`

Comment: use foldername/stylesheetname.css for your problem the folderpath is realative to your index file

Comment: The problem is the body has no height so it cant change the color for the body, in the styles you have to add some height

Comment: @AhmedMahmud let's not assume the OP has no content on the page

Comment: Do you have content in index.html?

Comment: @AhmedMahmud I don't think you need to specify the height to body.

Comment: Oh well it may be the problem if he does not have content in his body

Comment: @AhmedMahmud is it a problem if you don't have content I am sure the body represents the whole page .Or maybe he hasn't specified body infront of curly braces

Comment: @RajeshPaudel So I tested it and the body has no height but adding background color changes the color of the whole page, so I guess I was wrong with what I though

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your CSS at least a height and width.

Try adding:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: You know what they say about assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
height:1000px;
width:100%;
```

You cannot give percentage to body height because body has no parent.

And add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

to `<head>` of html file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working locally, the `/style.css` reference will try to load the file from the root of your filesystem. Same thing applies if you're loading from a subfolder in a domain, it will try to look for the file at the root of the domain folder.

If you change it to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` (notice the missing slash) it will then try to find the `style.css` file in the folder relative to the `index.html` file, which is the same.

The background will then be yellow.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is you need to have relative file path to your stylesheet.In your case imagining you have style.css inside css folder you need to do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

> Remember / path is for absolute path of file. This means that it
>   represents your file path from the root directory. And without / the file path becomes relative

Since you said you were beginner this may be another issue. Maybe be you haven't specified where to apply your style

```
    body{
       background-color:yellow;
    }
```

Comment: About the where the OP hasn't specified where to apply the style, its in the question that he has writte `body { background-color: yellow; }`

Answer (score 0):

If your html page has nothing in it (text or images) then it is difficult to see any bg color since it has no height/width, as mentioned above.

Insert some dummy text to see if this is the case.
If you only have one css file, it is not unusual to have it in the same folder as the index.html file, and in this case change the code to:

This may be the case since you indicate that both files are in the same root folder, so delete the "/" since that would mean the css is not being applied.
It is worth naming the stylesheet to something relevent to the site you are working on, such as catstyle.css or lollipopstyle.css so that, if you have many css files open in your text editor, you can clearly see which one is for which site.

I am assuming also that you have the skeletal structure of the html "bare bones" complete as shown [here](http://media02.hongkiat.com/html-css-faster-emmet/html5-structure.jpg/).
Make sure to put the link to the stylesheet inside the  section, say, after the meta-charset line.